# window.open with French characters in the url

Tags: java, javascript, utf-8, httprequest, http-get

I use window.open to open a popup with French accented characters in the url.

When a new popup opens, I see the French characters properly displayed in the url.

ie.
http://example.com/alt_title=Thierry%20Frémaux%3A%20Les%20confiden

However, when the request is processed by the Java web app and the get parameters are parsed, the French accented characters all become corrupted inside the HttpRequest object.

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

The Url is constructed using javascript. The js actually extracts the values of the input tags inside a form to build that ULR. So, it'll be tricky to encode the url in Java

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
String correctUrl = URLEncoder.encode(myurl);
```

edited:

oops sorry thought it was java... here is the equivalent code in js:

```
var correcturl = encodeURIComponent(myurl);
```

Comment: Thanks yeahman! I tried to run this in javascript console in Chrome.

window.open(encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/alt_title=Thierry%20Frémaux%3A%20Les%20confiden'))

The popup page shows

http://example.com/alt_title=Thierry%20FrÃ©maux%3A%20Les%20confiden was not found on this server.

Comment: The characters seem corrupted still.

Comment: the characters are corrupted in the http request constructed in your java app? then you should use URLEncoder.encode in your java app before constructing it

Answer (score 0):

Encoding them like the other special characters in the URL should work out. The character "é" for instance is %E9.

Comment: Thanks Per. How could I do that in javascript?